# My array for particles isn't working (C++/Particle System)

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, particles, particle-system

I am trying to make a simple particle system to make a smoke effect for a tire & wheel I made in opengl. After searching, I found particle systems can be used for this. I've never made a particle system so I tried to see if I could find any online that I could just modify for my specific purpose but no luck so here I am trying to make my own.

I have a framework that allows me to make only one particle that is made from where I click on the screen. After being made, the particle will just fall down off screen. I was then able to modify the code to then be able to make 2 show up by copying and pasting the code I used to make the first single one(but just changing the variable name). From this I then knew I could make as many particles as I want with a for loop and an array(at least I think I could). However, it doesn't really do what I was hoping. Before doing this, I had only two particles that would appear after I would click anywhere on the screen. Now, after implementing my array of particles, I removed the second particle(as shown in code below) and replaced it with my array. `MAX_PARTICLES` is only set to 5 just to test it. Yet, only one particle shows and it also doesn't move... It is stuck at the spot where I clicked for the particles to appear from.

[image: Here is a picture of what it was before making an array for particles.]

[image: Here is a picture of what it is now after making an array for particles.]

I don't understand why it is that only one particle of the array shows and also why it doesn't move. My assumption is the `g.particle` address is not being accessed in my `movement()` or my `render()`. But I don't know how to fix it. Below is my code for `movement()` and also `render()`.

```cpp
 void movement()
 {
     if (g.n <= 0)
         return;
     Particle *p = &g.particle;
     p->s.center.x += p->velocity.x;
     p->s.center.y += p->velocity.y;

     //this commented code is me making another particle
     /*Particle *b = &g.particles[0];
     b->s.center.x += b->velocity.x;
     b->s.center.y += b->velocity.y;*/

     Particle b[MAX_PARTICLES];
     for(int i=0; i<MAX_PARTICLES; i++)
     {
         b[i] = g.particles[i];
         b[i].s.center.x += b[i].velocity.x;
         b[i].s.center.y += b[i].velocity.y;
     }

     //check for off-screen
     if (p->s.center.y < 0.0) {
         cout << "off screen" << endl;
         g.n = 0;
     }   
 }

 void render()
 {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     //Draw shapes...
     //draw the box
     Shape *s;
     glColor3ub(90,140,90);
     s = &g.box;
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(s->center.x, s->center.y, s->center.z);
     float w, h;
     w = s->width;
     h = s->height;
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     glVertex2i(-w, -h);
     glVertex2i(-w,  h);
     glVertex2i( w,  h);
     glVertex2i( w, -h);
     glEnd();
     glPopMatrix();
     //
     //Draw particles here
     if (g.n > 0) {
         //There is at least one particle to draw.
         glPushMatrix();
         glColor3ub(150,160,220);
         Vec *c = &g.particle.s.center;
         w = h = 2;
         glBegin(GL_QUADS);
         glVertex2i(c->x-w, c->y-h);
         glVertex2i(c->x-w, c->y+h);
         glVertex2i(c->x+w, c->y+h);
         glVertex2i(c->x+w, c->y-h);
         glEnd();
         glPopMatrix();

         /*below code is commented out because it was just me 
         trying to make another particle.*/

         //second particle
         /*glPushMatrix();
         glColor3ub(150,160,220);
         Vec *d = &g.particles[0].s.center;
         w = h = 2;
         glBegin(GL_QUADS);
         glVertex2i(d->x-w, d->y-h);
         glVertex2i(d->x-w, d->y+h);
         glVertex2i(d->x+w, d->y+h);
         glVertex2i(d->x+w, d->y-h);
         glEnd();
         glPopMatrix(); */


         //making a for loop to draw all the particles.
         for(int i=0; i<MAX_PARTICLES; i++)
         {
             glPushMatrix();
             glColor3ub(150,160,220);
             Vec *d = &g.particles[i].s.center;
             w = h = 2;
             glBegin(GL_QUADS);
             glVertex2i(d->x-w, d->y-h);
             glVertex2i(d->x-w, d->y+h);
             glVertex2i(d->x+w, d->y+h);
             glVertex2i(d->x+w, d->y-h);
             glEnd();
             glPopMatrix(); 
         }
     }
```

As shown, I basically took the given code for making a single particle and tried to make an array that makes 5 particles at once. Just in case there is a problem with how I make the particles, here the code for that as well, for you all to check:

```cpp
 void makeParticle(int x, int y)
 {   
     //Add a particle to the particle system.
     // 
     if (g.n >= MAX_PARTICLES)
         return;
     cout << "makeParticle() " << x << " " << y << endl;
     //set position of particle
     Particle *p = &g.particle;
     p->s.center.x = x;
     p->s.center.y = y;
     p->velocity.y = -4.0;
     p->velocity.x =  1.0;

     /*Particle *v = &g.particles[0];
     v->s.center.x = x;
     v->s.center.y = y;
     v->velocity.y = -5.0;
     v->velocity.x =  1.0; */

     float vy = -5.0;
     for(int i=0; i<MAX_PARTICLES; i++)
     {
         Particle *v = &g.particles[i];
         v->s.center.x = x;
         v->s.center.y = y;
         v->velocity.y = vy;
         v->velocity.x =  1.0;
         vy--;
     }
     ++g.n;
 }
```

Please help me out figure out what I did wrong that isn't allowing me to properly make the particles using an array. I have a feeling it's just I'm not accessing `g.particles` correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
b[i] = g.particles[i];
```

you *copy* the object into the array `b`. All the changes you make to `b[i]` will be on that object only.

As I see it the array `b` isn't actually needed, all you need is a reference to the object `g.particles[i]`:

```
Particle& b = g.particles[i];
b.s.center.x += b.velocity.x;
b.s.center.y += b.velocity.y;
```

Comment: YES! That fixed it! You the man. Thank you very much. I really need to practice more with pointers.. lol